# Code Snippets in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, xcode6

In Xcode 5 the pre-defined code snippets are located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECodeSnippetLibrary.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets`.

In Xcode 6 `IDECodeSnippetLibrary.ideplugin` no longer exists in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/`.

Where are Xcode 6's built in code snippets located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default snippets are now located in the **IDEKit** framework:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets
```

Answer (score 3):

The snippets have been rolled into the IDEKit framework, instead of a separate plugin.

You can find the snippets in the file `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets` .

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 10, it's now newly located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESourceEditor.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets`